# Why some variables have changed and some have not?

Tags: python

Why the variables a, c, d have not changed, but b has changed?

```
a = 0
b = []
c = []
d = 'a'


def func_a(a):
    a += 1
    
    
def func_b(b):
    b += [1]
    
    
def func_c(c):
    c = [2]
    
    
def func_d(d):
    d += 'd'
    
    
func_a(a)
func_b(b)
func_c(c)
func_d(d)
print('a = ', a)
print('b = ', b)
print('c = ', c)
print('d = ', d)
```

I think it has to do with the fact that all variables are global, but I don't understand why b changes then..

Comment: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html is the best explanation of how Python names work I know of

Comment: Variables a and d are immutable so you're passing them by value and the "change" is only taking place within the function

Comment: "I think it has to do with the fact that all variables are global" No; **none** of them are global. Each function reads `a`, `b`, `c` or `d` respectively from its *parameter*, which is inherently local. This is a question about **pass by reference**, so I have linked the appropriate canonical.

Answer (score 0):

This is related by local and global scope, you can update using change the name of function parameter names;

```
a = 0


def func_a(local_a):
    global a
    a += 1

func_a(a)
print('a = ', a)
# output: a =  1
```

"global a" meaning this function will use the global scope of a.

If you try to use with this way;

```
a = 0
b = []
c = []
d = 'a'


def func_a(a):
    global a
    a += 1

func_a(a)
print('a = ', a)
```

You will get an error like this;

```
  File "glob_and_local.py", line 8
    global a
    ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: name 'a' is parameter and global
```

Because same names are conflicting.

Answer (score 0):

Here, `a, b, c, d` are global variables.

For a:
`a` is an integer. when you are calling `func_a(a)` you are only making changes in the local scope but not returning anything. That's why there is no change in the global variable `a`.
Same thing happening with global variables `c` and `d`.

For b:

You are passing an array and appending an array into it.
append method makes changes in global variables too.

NOTE:

here, `b += [1]` is equivalent to `b.append(1)`